# bitcoin-cli not working

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli

Whenever I try running some command like:
bitcoin-cli getinfo
The prompt just hangs and does not return anything, similar to SQL interface if you do not enter semicolon.
Running only "bitcoin-cli" returns the help screen but running any command just hangs and need to press CTRL+C to get back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many commands block the daemon from responding to requests, and during startup you'll not get responses while the node is initializing.

Comment: actually the bitcoind was restarting continuously in background due to error, once the error was fixed, everything worked.